# Passing string as PChar from CSharp to Delphi DLL

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, import

I'm trying to pass a string from C# to Delphi built DLL.
Delphi DLL expects PChar.

Here is Delphi export

```
procedure DLL_Message(Location:PChar;AIntValue :integer);stdcall;
external 'DLLTest.dll';
```

C# import(last one I tried, there were string, char* ref string ...)

```
[DllImport(
            "DLLTest.dll", 
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            EntryPoint = "DLL_Message"
        )]
        public static extern void DLL_Message(IntPtr Location, int AIntValue);
```

I get access violation accessing value in any way.

Is there any solution to pass a string value as PChar in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the MarshalAs attribute that allows you to control the native type that is used.

A list of types can be found in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx

```
DllImport(
            "DLLTest.dll", 
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
            EntryPoint = "DLL_Message"
        )]
        public static extern void DLL_Message(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string Location,
            int AIntValue
        );
```

Comment: MarshalAs not needed here. That's default marshaling. Likewise for the parameters to the DllImport attribute. Only filename is needed.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Isn't the default UnmanagedType.LPWStr (UTF-16)?

Comment: I've read the documentation again and still conclude that the default is BStr. Where does it say the default is LPStr?

Comment: It doesn't. But if you don't specify with MarshalAs you get LPTStr